# Creating an Attachment Match Table when file names are not an exact match to key field

Tags: arcgis-pro, attachments

I have a bunch of files to attach to lines, most lines have one file but a couple have multiple. When the files were created they were given an extra space at the end. With the space in the file name I get an warning message and an empty match table. If I remove the space it seems to work fine for the feature with one file to attach.

Is there a way to get the tool to match based on the first part of the file names so I don't have to rename them all? and for it to recognize the filenames that have (2) at the end? I thought it might work using a the wildcard * and a space but I get an empty match table.

Comment: If the extra space is consistent for all filenames it might be easier to use PowerShell or Python to remove the trailing space from the end of all the filenames all at once. I would take a backup of your data first.